# akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider not found

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka, akka-http, akka-cluster

I am trying to run my play application with akka cluster. i have added dependencies in my build.sbt file and changes are reflected in my jar list. Still while running my application it is giving me "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider" error. Any idea??

This is snapshot from my build.sbt file
[image: This is snapshot from my build.sbt file]

This is snapshot from jar folder

[image: This is snapshot from jar folder]

Answer (score 1):

Have you also configured akka properly? [Here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/cluster-usage.html#A_Simple_Cluster_Example) you can find an example of a simple setup. The key things that need to be set are the `actor provider` and the `remote settings`.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the right config, make sure to add the dependency, which was my mistake.
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % AkkaVersion
[For more see the documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-usage.html?language=java#A_Simple_Cluster_Example)